# Check if string contains word at start of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I am starting to learn a little bit more advanced js and i want to check if string contains a word at the start of the line.
Something like this would be good!:

```
var string = "Hello world";
if (string.contains("Hello", start) == true)
{
console.log("success");
}
```

Comment: Im sorry about not mentioning that i want it to work in node js

Answer (score 6):

Very easy Method:

```
var str = "Hello World";

if (str.startsWith("Hello")){
    do stuff;
}
```

You could also make two arrays and compare the single letters using a for loop, slightly more creative :D

Comment: Thx it worked great

Comment: But not in node js now when i tested it sorry

Comment: You could do it "manually",but I'll post it in another answer so I have the code format.

Comment: var str = "Hello World"; var test = "Hello";       var size = test.length;              if ( test ==   str.substring(0,size)){ do stuff;}

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fullString.substring(0, stringToFind.length) == stringToFind) {

}
```

Comment: This worked to but it was a little long

Comment: Seems to not work in node.js tho

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you can use startsWith: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith.

Otherwise you can use RegExp with '^' which matches the beginning of input (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) like this: `/^Hello/.test('Hello World')`